# SSO Authentication for Node.js REST API (cansecurity, passport)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, passport.js

I have been working to build a simple REST API to a database through Node.js, and am hoping to implement a basic single-sign-on structure with authorization rules for different users.  I started off using [passport](http://passportjs.org/) (specifically passport-local), which does a good job of authenticating and making easy login/logout services -- but seems to not be friendly with a stateless setup.

In researching further, I came across [cansecurity](https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity) and think it has the functionality I'm looking for.  After reading through the documentation, there are a few things I am having trouble with in really getting into this:

**1) How do I actually send a login/logout request?**

I see how cansecurity allows for authorization for different routes, and I wrote a validation function to check hashed passwords, retrieve the user, etc. But does anyone have any insight into actually performing the single-sign-on to get a user logged in?

**2) Is there an easy way to integrate the access information into an external source?**

Ideally, I'd like to have a mobile app using the API to perform database operations (hence the desire to have SSO and a fairly robust authorization framework).

If anyone has used either passport or cansecurity for a similar setup, how did you do it and what steps may I be missing?

**SETTING UP CANSECURITY:**

```
var cs = require('cansecurity')
    , cansec = cs.init( 
    {
        sessionExpiry: 60, 
        sessionKey: SESSIONKEY,
        validate: 
            function(username, password, done) {
                User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(false, null, { message: 'Incorrect username.' }, null);
                    }
                    if(password !== undefined){
                        user.validPassword(password, function(err, result) {
                            if (result == true) return done(true, user, null, user.password);
                            else return done(false, null, {message: 'Incorrect password.'}, null);
                        });
                    }
                    else return done(true, user, null, user.password);
                });
        }
    })
```

**SETTING UP PASSPORT**

```
//passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
   function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
         if (err) return done(err);
         if (!user) {
             return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
         }
         user.validPassword(password, function(err, result) {
             if (result == true) return done(null, user);
             else return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password.'});
         });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.get(id, function(err, user) {
       done(err, user);
   });
});

// Routes
//login
app.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
                                       failureRedirect: '/',
                                       failureFlash: false })
);

//logout
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
   req.logout();
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!). They've got a completely prebuilt MVC framework built on Node, and it integrates seemlessly with Passport.js.

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, I ended up using Passport to solve the problem with specific endpoints for login, logout, token refresh, etc.  I used the [passport-http-bearer](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer) protocol to get it up and running.

For my purposes, Sails was a bit overkill.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to put that explanation in an answer and validate it, so it doesn't show up in unanswered questions anymore. Cheers.